# How to have several handlers using Logbook?

Tags: python, logging, logbook

I'm using [logbook](https://logbook.readthedocs.io/) to log message in a Python app but

```
import logbook

from logbook import Logger, StreamHandler, NullHandler

log = Logger('LogbookExample')

import sys
StreamHandler(sys.stdout).push_application()

NullHandler().push_application()

def main():
    log.info('Hello, World!')    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

doesn't work as I was expecting...
nothing appears. Like if `NullHandler` was replacing `StreamHandler`

So I wonder how to have several handlers connected to app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is choosing `NullHandler`. It acts as a "black hole", swallowing all logs and not propagating them up the stack.

Stacking non-`NullHandler`s is easy:

```
StreamHandler(sys.stdout).push_application()
StreamHandler(sys.stderr, bubble=True).push_application()
```

The `bubble` keyword means the handler should continue propagation up the stack after handling the record.